# How to import Java files directly from a URL?

Tags: java, android, url, import

I have uploaded a few .java files (along with .class and all required files) on my web server. I want to know if there is a way to include these files in another Java code that is on my client machine.

For example, in php, we can use include and set the URL and all its content will be merged with the current file on run time.

But in java I see only import. And for this the files should be locally available. Is there a way to import them from a URL?

If yes, how? If no, can someone provide another way to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt, that this is possible for an android app (for security reasons). In general, there is no problem downloading class-files and then loading them with a classloader.

I would package all the classes and resources into a single .jar-file and load it using an `URLClassLoader`. See this [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html)

Comment: The only reason I thought about this is because I want to reduce the file size of my app. Thanks for the answer!